# get class name of a selected option

Tags: jquery

I have a select tag which pretty much looks like this

```
<select name="platform">
    <option class="one-test-one">one</option>
    <option class="two-test-two">two</option>
    <option class="three-test-three">three</option>
</select>
<div class="clickMe">click</div>
```

I am trying to get the class attribute value of the the selected option. This is what I am doing in jquery

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {
    alert($('select[name="platform"]:selected').attr('class')); 
});
```

the alert is returning undefined ..what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) is applicable for `option`, not for the `select` so

```
$('select[name="platform"] :selected').attr('class')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lpzbttrq/)

Comment: @arun..so i am looking at your code..and all I was missing was space before the : ? Is that all it was?

Comment: @soum yes... the space makes a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) so it looks for the option inside the select... so the space changes the entire meaning of the selector

Comment: you learn something new every single day :-) thanks for pointing this out man :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
<select name="platform">
<option class="one-test-one">one</option>
<option class="two-test-two">two</option>
<option class="three-test-three">three</option>
</select>
<div class="clickMe">click</div>




$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {
alert($('select[name="platform"] option:selected').attr('class')); 
});

check in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ruapce/o11o1r6k/
```

Answer (score 2):

The `'selected'` selector is for `option` in `select` so try this :-

```
$('select[name="platform"] option:selected').attr('class');
```

EDIT :

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/an7ht8qv/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {
    alert($('select[name="platform"]').find(':selected').attr('class')); 
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/set1hdhy/

Answer (score 0):

Try this i have tested it

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function() {

   console.log($('select option:selected').attr('class')); 
});
```

Comment: yeah it works but the problem is I need have to have a unique selector so in my case I am using name=platform

Comment: so you can use this
console.log($('select[name="platform"] option:selected').attr('class'));

Comment: yeah..thats what I ended up using..what Arun actually suggested before...it works..I was missing that space which was causing that trouble..never knew about that